# App making impossible to use an Android smartphone during night

Tags: android

I am looking for an app that would block (or at least make noticeably harder) to use smartphone during night.

Mandatory

- app is not requiring access to phone logs or access to contacts or other permission not required for working
- app is making noticeably harder to use phone during night, so it is no longer possible to open browser after midnight and start browsing

Nice to have

- configurable meaning of night (for example ability to set it from 0:00-4:00)
- app resistant to switching system time (so I am unable to change system time to 5:00 to bypass block)
- works out of box, without configuration
- I can still make and receive calls
- open source

I found following apps that seemed promising but failed to pass my requirements:

Offtime - I used it so far, but it recently started to require access to contacts and phone logs (also for users who paid for a full version) and it is no longer meaningful barrier to using phone during night

AppBlock, Freedom is not allowing to block all apps, you can block only specific ones (so any newly installed will not be blocked).

AppDetox is toothless with block not working at all.

Flipd has no support for blocking of apps

I am fine with paid apps. But I prefer open source ones after Offtime fiasco where I paid for a full version that was wrecked days later and replaced by an useless husk trying to get access to as much of my private data as possible.